# text editor that works direct on a server? (aptana?)

Tags: javascript, php, html, text-editor

Are there any good free text editors i can use directly on the server if i give it my ftp details?

failing that one with a good save-to-ftp shortcut (ie ctrl-shift-s)

I work with mainly php and jquery, my primary editor is aptana?

Answer (score 1):

A possibility, at least with Eclipse *(I've used this with Eclipse PDT once or twice)*,  could be the [Target Management (RSE)](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/) plugin :

> The Target Management project creates
>   data models and frameworks to
>   configure and manage remote (mainframe
>   down to embedded) systems, their
>   connections, and their services.

It allows one to have Eclipse work on remote files as if they where stored on the local file-system -- i.e. each time a file is saved, it is *pushed* to the remote system.

Considering Aptana is based on Eclipse, this might work with Aptana too...

Comment: I agree. There's no need to leave Aptana unless you want another editor.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are developing under linux, you can use curlftpfs to mount an ftp connection into your filesystem, then you can use your editor of choice.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) has an [FTP plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/FTP_synchronize/) that works quite well.  [This article](http://www.rarst.net/software/notepadpp-ftp-plugin/) describes how to get it all set up.

Answer (score 0):

I use Notepad++.  You can start an ftp session and work directly from the ftp site.  http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm

Answer (score 0):

Any GNOME or KDE editor under *nix supports this, and with gvfs *any* editor can use FTP-based files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access at all, Nano is a great editor.

But like Ignacio sai, Gnome and KDE can hook up to your server and live edit files like that. Since it mounts the online filesystem, I could see Aptana working with that too.

Answer (score 0):

On the *Windows* platform the [Zeus Lite](http://www.zeusedit.com/lite) editor is *free* and it can can directly edit files on the server via *FTP*.